# While I'm trying to read an input in doPost(), I'm getting "org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException"

Tags: java, jetty-9

My jetty server version is "9.3.10.v20160621".Below is stack trace--

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.println(ResponseWriter.java:414)
at com.abc.servlet.BedListAdminServlet.handleChooseFromBedsOnNetwork(BedListAdminServlet.java:929)
at com.abc.servlet.BedListAdminServlet.handleEvent(BedListAdminServlet.java:322)
at com.abc.servlet.BaseServletEventHandler.doPost(BaseServletEventHandler.java:56)
at com.abc.servlet.BedListAdminServlet.doFilteredGet(BedListAdminServlet.java:293)
at com.abc.servlet.BaseServletEventHandler.doGet(BaseServletEventHandler.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:697)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:746)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:441)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Utf8HttpWriter.write(Utf8HttpWriter.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpWriter.write(HttpWriter.java:65)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.println(ResponseWriter.java:415)
at com.abc.servlet.BedListAdminServlet.handleChooseFromBedsOnNetwork(BedListAdminServlet.java:927)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177)
... 47 more
```

I'm facing this issue only CentOS 7, when I run the same on Windows laptop, I don't face any exceptions. Any help, will be appreciated..

Comment: How often does the exception happen?  Are there any differences in your Jetty or JVM configuration on Windows versus Linux?

Comment: ck1- Exception occurs for every operation. Both Java and Jetty version are same on Windows & Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 
ContextHandler.setMaxFormContentSize(int maxSizeInBytes);
ContextHandler.setMaxFormKeys(int formKeys);
in your java class then you will not get that exception.

You can solve this problem in three ways one with vm arguments,Java code and through configuration xml files.

Below is the link from jetty
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-form-size.html